# How to add an incremental counter to Animation Style for a WPF shape

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, styles

I need to add something that works like a counter and detects how many times a shape (rectangle) has been hovered and accordingly changes the animation style by a bit.

**Background**: I have a grid of cells (Rectangles) that each have a mouse hover event. There are two types of cells; cell type 1 are normal cells and must turn green on hover and back to their original transparent color on end of mouse hover. Type 2 cells are special and must turn green when hovered and remain so even if the mouse leaves the rectangle.

**Code being used:**

```
Style PrepareAnimationStyle(int cellType)
        {
            Trigger animTrigger = new Trigger();
            animTrigger.Property = ContentElement.IsMouseOverProperty; 

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation greenStroke = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            //greenStroke.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation greenFill = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            //greenFill.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation transparentFill = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Colors.Transparent, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation silverStroke = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Colors.Silver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard sbEnter = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(greenStroke, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(greenFill, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
            sbEnter.Children.Add(greenStroke);
            sbEnter.Children.Add(greenFill);

            Storyboard sbExit = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(silverStroke, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(transparentFill, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
            sbExit.Children.Add(silverStroke);
            sbExit.Children.Add(transparentFill);

           animTrigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbEnter });
            if (cellType != 2) //regular cells
                animTrigger.ExitActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbExit });

            Style cellStyle = new Style();
            cellStyle.Triggers.Add(animTrigger);

            return cellStyle;
        }
```

**Problem:** This code works fine if there was no condition for the number of hover turns. Now, I am stumped as to how I can introduce a counter that can change the shade/opacity of the special cell as it is hovered. I can make three different shades - lightGreen, medGreen, darkGreen and use them or I can use an opacity variable and incrementally increase it; but I do not understand how I can use the existing code to keep a check of what the value of this counter will be and how I can apply the necessary entry animation style. This is how I am creating my cells:

```
grid.Children.Add(new Rectangle()
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Silver,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                Height = cellSize,
                Width = cellSize,
                Style = PrepareAnimationStyle(cellType)
            });
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using attached properties

let's start with the rect generation

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
    {
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver),
        StrokeThickness = 2,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
        Height = cellSize,
        Width = cellSize,
        Style = (cellType != 2) ? PrepareAnimationStyle(cellType) : null
    };
    if (cellType == 2)
        rect.SetValue(AnimationHelper.IsNonRegularCellProperty, true);
    grid.Children.Add(rect);
```

note that it is important to initialize the color values as `new SolidColorBrush(Colors...)` for the approach to work, also the style is not required in this case for the non regular cells

we will attach a property `AnimationHelper.IsNonRegularCellProperty` with value true to enable out custom animation.

AnimationHelper class

```
    class AnimationHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsNonRegularCell.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNonRegularCellProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsNonRegularCell", typeof(bool), typeof(AnimationHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsNonRegularCellChanged));

        private static void OnIsNonRegularCellChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = d as Rectangle;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                //to make sure I set the color values again
                rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
                rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                rect.SetValue(HoverCountProperty, default(byte));
                rect.MouseEnter += rect_MouseEnter;
            }
            else
            {
                rect.MouseEnter -= rect_MouseEnter;
            }
        }

        static void rect_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

            byte hoverCount = (byte)rect.GetValue(HoverCountProperty);
            hoverCount++;
            if (hoverCount > 3)
                return;
            rect.SetValue(HoverCountProperty, hoverCount);
            byte alpha = (byte)(85 * hoverCount);
            ColorAnimation anim = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Color.FromArgb(alpha, 0x66, 0xcc, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            rect.Fill.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, anim);
            rect.Stroke.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, anim);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HoverCount.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverCountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HoverCount", typeof(byte), typeof(AnimationHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(byte)));
    }
```

above animation will animate to a color with increased alpha by 33% every-time so reaching to 100% in 3 mouse hovers.